# Association rule mining on a GPU machine

Tags: python

I have an association rule mining code written in python.
It will generate the frequent patterns and also the itemset rules.
But it taking a long time to execute because of the data size.
can anyone guide me on how to run the same on a GPU machine? Not google collab but a normal v100 tesla card GPU machine.